# Possible to use value of an array's subdocument in an expression during mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have this document:

```
{
  _id: 0,
  array: [{a: 120}, {a: 2452}]
}
```

And I want to obtain:

```
{
  _id: 0,
  array: [{a: 120}, {a: 2452}],
  a1x2: 240 // array[0].a * 2
}
```

Currently the simplest way I can think of to do this, in an aggregation, is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $match: {}
}, {
  $set: {aTmp: {$arrayElemAt: ["$array", 0]}}
}, {
  $project: {
    array: 1,
    a1x2: {$multiply: ["$aTmp.a", 2]},
    aTmp: 0
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the intermediary step of setting `aTmp`? I don't know how to get a subdocument's value for a key when it's in the form of  `{$arrayElemAt: ["$array", 0]}`.

I also tried using `$array.0.a` and `$array[0].a`, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
      a1x2: { $let: {
          vars: {
            aTmp: {$arrayElemAt: ["$array", 0]}
          },
          in: {$multiply: ["$$aTmp.a", 2]}
      }}
  } }
])
```